# Split a string by list of character positions

Tags: python, string

Suppose you have a string:

```
text = "coding in python is a lot of fun"
```

And character positions:

```
positions = [(0,6),(10,16),(29,32)]
```

These are intervals, which cover certain words within text, i.e. coding, python and fun, respectively.

Using the character positions, how could you split the text on those words, to get this output:

```
['coding','in','python','is a lot of','fun']
```

This is just an example, but it should work for any string and any list of character positions.

I'm not looking for this:

`[text[i:j] for i,j in positions]`

Comment: Do you know that you can use something like `text[0:5]` (a "string slice")?

Comment: Because you are splitting the text on the words that lie within the ranges specified by character positions. You're not creating a list of text within each range, which would return 3 strings for each of the 3 ranges of character positions. It's like I want text.split(on a list of character ranges)

Comment: What is the relation between the character positions and the string? Looks like they are unrelated according to the expected output

Comment: The character positions give the beginning and end positions of the words "coding", "python" and "fun" within `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd flatten `positions` to be `[0,6,10,16,29,32]` and then do something like

```py
positions.append(-1)
prev_positions = [0] + positions
words = []
for begin, end in zip(prev_positions, positions):
    words.append(text[begin:end])
```

This exact code produces `['', 'coding', ' in ', 'python', ' is a lot of ', 'fun', '']`, so it needs some additional work to strip the whitespace

Comment: Change it to positions.append(None), then do [word.strip() for word in words if word.strip()], then it seems to work for a bunch of different test cases.

Comment: @Data why do you suggest `None`? I've added `-1` because `'fun'` may not be at the end of the sentence, so after slicing it we need to slice the remaining part of the sencence (`text[fun_end:-1]`)

Comment: @Data, I've double-checked, you're right. `-1` is a bug from me, it omits the very last character, while `None` doesn't

Comment: With -1, sometimes the end character is missed out

Answer (score 0):

Below code works as expected

```
text = "coding in python is a lot of fun"
positions = [(0,6),(10,16),(29,32)]
textList = []
lastIndex = 0
for indexes in positions:
    s = slice(indexes[0], indexes[1])
    if positions.index(indexes) > 0:
        print(lastIndex)
        textList.append(text[lastIndex: indexes[0]])
    textList.append(text[indexes[0]: indexes[1]])
    lastIndex = indexes[1] + 1
print(textList)
```

Output: ['coding', 'in ', 'python', 'is a lot of ', 'fun']

Note: If space are not needed you can trim them